# Does Erlang Have Map?

Tags: erlang

It seems that Erlang introduced maps in version R17A.

But, if I go to the [downloads](http://www.erlang.org/download.html) page, I only see version 17.5, there's no version R17A.

So, is it released and stable yet? Does the latest stable Erlang has Map support?

Comment: Not really a question for this kind of forum.

Comment: With erlang version 17 the way of naming erlang versions changed form the old R16B3 type to the new 17.3. I honestly don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since the release version R17 - somewhere early 2014 - Erlang supports maps. You can read all about it at http://learnyousomeerlang.com/maps. You should go for the latest release, being 17.5.

Answer (score 1):

Correct Erlang Map is rather recent. It's introduced under EEP43
https://www.erlang.org/erlang-enhancement-proposals/eep-0043.html

In fact, Map addresses a number of issues with record. The EEP explains them.